# I have a trouble with the function slideToggle()

Tags: jquery, prestashop, slidetoggle

I'im using prestashop and I have a problem.

I have two buttons : Guest checkout and Create an account and a similar div #opc_account_form for the form.

The thing is the slideToggle doesn't work well.

1) If i click on Guest checkout, the form slide down and if i click an other time on Guest checkout, the form slide up (no problem on this one)

2) If i click on Create an account, the form slide down and if i click an other time on Create an account, the form slide up (no problem on this one)

3) Here the problem : If i click on Guest checkout, the form slide down and if i click on Create an account the form slide up. Normally, it had to slide up Guest checkout's form and slide down  Create an account's form  (i have to click on other time)

Any Idea ,

Thanks

Here the code

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', '#opc_createAccount', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#opc_account_form').slideToggle('slow');


     });
     $(document).on('click', '#opc_guestCheckout', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#opc_account_form').slideToggle('slow');
     });

 });
```

```css
.unvisible {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="opc_account-group">
    <form id="new_account_form" class="std" autocomplete="on" autofill="on">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="box">
                <div id="opc_account_choice" class="row">
                    <p class="opc-button">
                        <button type="submit" id="opc_guestCheckout"><span>Guest checkout</span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                    <p class="opc-button">
                        <button type="submit" id="opc_createAccount"><span>Create an account</span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                    <!-- <h3 id="new_account_title" class="page-subheading"></h3>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="opc_account_form" class="unvisible">
                <p>here the form</p>
```

Comment: Protip: if the click events have the same function, use comma seperated selectors to reduce code clutter

Comment: So both forms is actually 1 form?

Comment: The main issue is you have 1 form but 2 places where you can toggle it and you don't know when you should be hiding/showing the form due to the 2 entry points. Guest checkout and Create an account sounds completely different and you should have 2 forms instead of one.

Comment: So does my solution not work for you? is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to want to have 2 separate Divs and not use toggle.

Click Guest should call hide create account (if its showing then its hidden, if not then nothing changes) and then call show guest check out div.

The click event for create account will do the same inverted, hide guest checkout and show create account

If there is a requirement so have the button clicks "toggle" their own div you could then call Toggle for the div they own and hide for the other div.

Here is an example from your original sample, few notes

1. used slide up to always hide the other div
2. having these 2 forms embedded will make validation a PAIN, be sure toggle the validation if the item is visible.
3. I changed the type of button to 'button' so they do not try to submit the form and you do not have to prevent default. but just an FYI you could also use

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', '#opc_createAccount', function (e) {
       //e.preventDefault();
       $('#guest_form').slideUp('slow');
       $('#opc_account_form').slideToggle('slow');
       


     });
     $(document).on('click', '#opc_guestCheckout', function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        $('#opc_account_form').slideUp('slow');
        $('#guest_form').slideToggle('slow');
     });

 });
```

```css
.unvisible {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <div id="opc_account-group">
    <form id="new_account_form" class="std" autocomplete="on" autofill="on">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="box">
                <div id="opc_account_choice" class="row">
                    <p class="opc-button">
                        <button type="button" id="opc_guestCheckout"><span>Guest checkout</span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                    <p class="opc-button">
                        <button type="button" id="opc_createAccount"><span>Create an account</span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                    <!-- <h3 id="new_account_title" class="page-subheading"></h3>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="opc_account_form" class="unvisible">
                <p>new account form</p>
          </div>
          <div id="guest_form" class="unvisible">
                <p>Guest form</p>
          </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
```